# Is there a way to read tags in Asana tasks?

Tags: api, asana

I'm using the Asana API and the "opt_expand=." option when reading all the tasks in a project. It returns me a lot of information but not the tags. Is there a way to read the tags associated with a task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I work for Asana)

The API does not expose tags yet, but it is high on our list of features to add.

Comment: For some background, we use the tags in QA to mark bugs as Fixed - then let QA close them out when confirmed. We <3 Asana regardless.

Answer (score -1):

Asana's API now has Tag support (added June 19, 2012) https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tags